# I need to linearly interpolate a numpy array of dimension nx3x3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, interpolation

I have a pretty simple question-

I'm looking for a way to interpolate a bunch of 3x3 matrices that I have stored in a 3D numpy array. Basically I need to repopulate a numpy array with intermediary matrix values calculated linearly just based on each element in their row/column.

Something that turns
`[[1 1 1], [1 1 1], [1 1 1]]`   (thats a 2x3x3 np.array)
`[[5 5 5], [5 5 5], [5 5 5]]`

into

`[[1 1 1], [1 1 1], [1 1 1]]`
`[[3 3 3], [3 3 3], [3 3 3]]`   (thats a 3x3x3 np.array)
`[[5 5 5], [5 5 5], [5 5 5]]`

but there needs to be about a hundred matrices between each matrix, then stored back into my Nx [3x3] numpy array.

Comment: check this out: `http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html`

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I've looked at that but couldn't make much sense of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).

In the following example, `a` is an array with shape (4, 3, 3).  The interpolated result, `b`, has shape (13, 3, 3).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

a = np.empty((4, 3, 3))
a[0, :, :] = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
a[1, :, :] = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
a[2, :, :] = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]
a[3, :, :] = [[5, 5, 5], [3, 4, 5], [20, 40, 60]]

# Create an x-coordinate for each 3x3 array in `a`.
x = np.arange(a.shape[0])

# Create a linear interpolator.
f = interp1d(x, a, axis=0)

# Insert `m` arrays between each 3x3 array in `a`.
m = 3
xx = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], (a.shape[0] - 1)*(m + 1) + 1)
b = f(xx)
```

Here are some of the values after running the script in an ipython session:

```
In [93]: a
Out[93]: 
array([[[  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.]],

       [[  1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [ 10.,  20.,  30.]],

       [[  5.,   5.,   5.],
        [  3.,   4.,   5.],
        [ 20.,  40.,  60.]]])

In [94]: x
Out[94]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [95]: xx
Out[95]: 
array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ,  1.25,  1.5 ,  1.75,  2.  ,
        2.25,  2.5 ,  2.75,  3.  ])

In [96]: b[:5]
Out[96]: 
array([[[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]],

       [[ 0.25,  0.25,  0.25],
        [ 0.25,  0.25,  0.25],
        [ 0.25,  0.25,  0.25]],

       [[ 0.5 ,  0.5 ,  0.5 ],
        [ 0.5 ,  0.5 ,  0.5 ],
        [ 0.5 ,  0.5 ,  0.5 ]],

       [[ 0.75,  0.75,  0.75],
        [ 0.75,  0.75,  0.75],
        [ 0.75,  0.75,  0.75]],

       [[ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
        [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
        [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ]]])

In [97]: b[-5:]
Out[97]: 
array([[[  1. ,   1. ,   1. ],
        [  1. ,   2. ,   3. ],
        [ 10. ,  20. ,  30. ]],

       [[  2. ,   2. ,   2. ],
        [  1.5,   2.5,   3.5],
        [ 12.5,  25. ,  37.5]],

       [[  3. ,   3. ,   3. ],
        [  2. ,   3. ,   4. ],
        [ 15. ,  30. ,  45. ]],

       [[  4. ,   4. ,   4. ],
        [  2.5,   3.5,   4.5],
        [ 17.5,  35. ,  52.5]],

       [[  5. ,   5. ,   5. ],
        [  3. ,   4. ,   5. ],
        [ 20. ,  40. ,  60. ]]])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the demo! however I realized that i made a small mistake in my matrix dimensions above (that I've changed)... i need to change Nx3x3 matrices into 10Nx3x3 matrices... the 'depth' of the matrix array is what needs to be increased, while smoothing the steps of the 3x3 matrices. I will try to use the example you provided to change the axis of interpolation...  thanks for the detailed response and if theres a quick way to change which axis it interps that would be awesome as well!

Comment: I can update my answer.  You should update your question with that additional information.

Comment: Niall, I updated the script.  That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: This is great- thanks a lot for *both* of your answers..the documentation on this stuff can sometimes be quite nebulous for a python novice. This technique seems like it would be the fastest for the task and thanks for the comments as well.